# How to make turn based card game using Game Center?

Tags: iphone, ios, game-center

I'm working on card game which is turn based.
This is short decription of structure of game:

1. Dealing 4 cards to every player
2. Random player is turning over 1 card, after him another (which has seen card of previous player) and etc.
3. On the end player with the highest card wins and dealing cards starts again

So my question is how to make turn based card game using Game Center and is i possible because I have not found any tutorial just like I need?

UPDATE:
And my second question is; Is it possible to players could make a room which then other players can join (over Game center)?

Answer (score 2):

As usual, nobody is going to give you a complete tutorial.
Im guessing your new at Obj-C.
But:

1. Learn about assigning UIImageViews Referencing Outlets.
2. Changing UIImageViews Images using code.
3. Importing Images.
4. Using IBActions
5. Using UIButtons (To Select A Card)
6. Use Custom UIButtons with a background image.
7. Using varibles to assign different cards. (Eg Card1 = "5Spades)
8. Put varibles in a list
9. Pick random numbers (depending on how much you want each player to get) out of amount of objects in a list
10. assign players those random numbers
11. allow players to select a card using UIButtons
12. Determine who had the biggest card. For example (If player1.selectedcard = 10 spades, etc)
13. repeat from step 9

None of the code examples will work!

Answer (score 2):

Of course did somebody wrote a whole tutorial. In this case a epic one. It is huge, professional and clean. The credit goes to the Netherlands to Matthijs Hollemans. It is using Gamecenter's Bluetooth functionality.

http://www.raywenderlich.com/12735/how-to-make-a-simple-playing-card-game-with-multiplayer-and-bluetooth-part-1

If you want to use Gamecenters turn based API than go ahead and read this tutorial:

http://www.raywenderlich.com/5480/beginning-turn-based-gaming-with-ios-5-part-1

With the knowledge of both tutorials will you be able to finish your game.